# Number of roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

I would like to know if anything can be said about the number of roots of a polynomial whose coefficients depend on the $x$, particularly,
$$x^2(f(x))^2-2xf(x)+g(x)=0$$

We further know that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are positive for all $x$.

From Descartes' rule of signs we know that there is no negative root and that there are at most 2 positive real roots. Can we say something more? Can we say under which conditions that polynomial has exactly one (double) real root?

Comment: It seems that you'll need further resrictions on $f$ and $g$ for this to even have _one_ root.

Comment: The roots should be:
$$x=\frac{1}{f(x)}\left(1\pm\sqrt{1-g(x)}\right)$$
If I look at the discriminant we see that $D=1-g(x)$, so only $g(x)$ should influence the number of roots. 
But I am not sure if this is a correct step. (To me it looks weird that the root $x$ depends on $x$...it's like some recursion). Am I wrong?

Comment: Just chose some $f(x), g(x)$ constant and then compute the solutions $\hat{x}_{1,2}$. Finally redefine $f(\hat{x}_{1,2})$ to be some other constant and you've destroyed your solution.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. What I know more about the $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is that they are both even functions (and positive). But I don't see how that can help me to estimate the number of roots..

Comment: It will still not be good to go, since you can redefine four values of $f$: $f(\pm\hat{x}_{1,2})$ to differ and still destroy it without destroying the symmetry of $f$.

Comment: So what you are saying is that there is no method to find the number of roots in this case? What would the functions have to satisfy to be able to say something (bounded, convex, monotonous)? Like if the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are ..., then...

Comment: My first guess would be at least continuity and maybe something like monotony. But that's an entriely different question.

Comment: Are $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ polynomials too?

Comment: Well, in my case they are quite complicated functions. Something like $\log f_1(x)\log\frac{f_2(x)}{f_3(x)}$. All I know (so far) is that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continous, differentiable, even, positive, with maximum at $x=0$. They look almost like some gaussians (one peak, long outliers -- depending on the $x$).

Comment: If $f$ and $g$ are not polynomials then $x^2(f(x))^2-2xf(x)+g(x)$ is not a polynomial, so you can't apply Descartes' rule of signs (unless there is a more general statement of it than the usual one?).

Comment: For example, if $f(x) = \exp(-\tfrac{3}{40}x^2)$ and $g(x) = \exp(-\tfrac{1}{40}x^2)$ then $x^2 f(x)^2 - 2 x f(x) + g(x)$ has four zeros in the interval $[0,10]$.

Comment: Thank you, Antonio! Nice example, indeed.
But what about the Descartes' rule for the negative values. I think at least that holds (that there is no negative root for any positive functions $f(x)$, $g(x)$). If you plug $-x$ for $x$, there is no sign change for any function whatsover. Or I'm wrong also there?

Comment: Again, Descartes' rule only works for polynomials.  It does not work here.  And there is a sign change in the term $-2xf(x)$.  I think whatever we could say about the roots really does depend on exactly what $f$ and $g$ are, so without more information there may not be a good answer.

Comment: Ohhh wait, I see what you're saying.  Yeah, if you replace $x$ with $-x$ then everything is positive, so it can't be zero.  Gotcha.